# PostgreSQL. constraint allowing only one of many possible values

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have statuses like this: `started`,`calculated`,`finished`
I need a constraint allowing only one NOT `finished` status in a table.

**This is allowed:**

```
+----+----------+
| id |  status  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | finished |
|  2 | finished |
|  3 | started  |
+----+----------+
```

```
+----+------------+
| id |   status   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | finished   |
|  2 | finished   |
|  3 | calculated |
+----+------------+
```

**this is forbidden due to two not finished statuses:**

```
+----+------------+
| id |   status   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | finished   |
|  2 | finished   |
|  3 | calculated |
|  4 | started    |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filtering unique index:

```
create unique index myindex
    on mytable ((1)) 
    where (status <> 'finished')
```

The trick is to pass a fixed value instead of a column name to the `on` clause of the index (we need two parentheses so Postgres evaluates this as an expression). This combines with a `where` clause that filters status other than "finished" to implement the logic you want.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=efcb2d0fc50193e180891c57cd6f82a2)**